# Redirect to login page if server returns 401 response

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-fetch-client

How can I intercept the server endpoint response and redirect an aurelia application to login page if is a 401 response?

I tried "withInterceptor(responseError() {...})" method of aurelia-fetch-client config, but I cannot return a "new Redirect(loginPage)"...

Anyone has an idea how to do it?

Comment: can't you inject the router and navigate to route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework'
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router'

@inject(HttpClient, Router)
export class UserService {
  http
  router

  constructor(http, router) {
    this.http = http
    this.router = router

    this.http.configure(config => {
      var self = this;
      config
      .withInterceptor({
        responseError(response) {
          if (response.status === 401) {
            self.router.navigateToRoute('login')
          }
          return response; // you can return a modified Response
        },
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: when I try to inject `Router`, the app does not load, with no error in the console. When I try to inject `AppRouter`, the does not load, but I see the following error in the console: `Error: History must implement activate().`. Have you experienced that?

Answer (score 0):

@Moustachiste fix same issue with this approach:

inject must be like this

```
constructor(
// private _router: Router
@lazy(Router) private _router: () => Router
)
```